# Combine audio and video to file in Gstreamer

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, h.264

On my Raspberry Pi i create a h.264 timelapse video from jpeg in gestreamer.

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=/home/pi/Timelapse/20160820/image_%04d.jpg index=0 \
caps="image/jpeg,framerate=\(fraction\)24/1" ! \
jpegdec ! \
queue ! \
omxh264enc target-bitrate=15000000 control-rate=variable ! \
video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=24/1,profile=high ! \
h264parse ! \
mp4mux faststart=true ! \
filesink location=/home/pi/Timelapse/20160820/1.mp4
```

This works pretty good. 
I also want to add a audio to the timelapse video. How can i use a mp3 file as background music and save combined file to disk?
Thanks.

Comment: give name to mp4mux with `name=mux` and use this as alias after the filesink like this `filesink loc....mp4  filesrc location=a.mp3 ! ... ! mux.` .. notice two spaces after ...mp4 .. figure out the rest if you can or ask as comment HTH

Comment: Thanks, i managed to get a video with sound.

I run into an issue, that the omx h.264 encoder does not support 1920x1080 because the resolution has to be divisible by 16 (1080 is not). This affects in a green line at the bottom of the video.
I tried to use a resolution of 1920x1088, but of course that is not a standard video format. 
I only can use the omx because of the hardware acceleration of the Raspberry Pi.
Any hints for that?
Thanks.

Comment: please ask this as another question.. you may answer this one with pipe that works for you.. glad you figured it out :)